# Fatal error when runing es() function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

`es` function in smooth package has a weird behavior for some short time-series. Here is a case:

```
require(smooth) # version 2.4.7

#create two time series of length 10
vec1_ts<-ts(c(36,24,51,7,7,77,1,29,19,2),start=c(2016,1),frequency=12)
vec2_ts<-ts(1:10,start=c(2016,1),frequency=12)

#this works:
es(vec1_ts)

#but this doesn't:
es(vec2_ts)

# another non-working example with a shorter length
vec3_ts<-ts(c(23,5,4,12,2,5),start=c(2016,1),frequency = 12)
es(vec3_ts)
```

I got a "R encountered a fatal error" message, and then forced to terminate the session when running es for the second time-series.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the function of that package. Can you, please, submit the bug here: https://github.com/config-i1/smooth/issues

The StackOverflow is not for solving problems of specific packages, it is for the solution of more general problems.

Comment: This has been fixed in v2.4.8.41009, which is currently on github: https://github.com/config-i1/smooth